# Nexus 4 KitKat: GPS_EVENT_STARTED and GPS_EVENT_STOPPED flapping

Tags: android, gps, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a gps listener to detect the GPS_EVENT_STARTED and GPS_EVENT_STOPPED event.

I noticed the events are happening on/off in sub-second frequency.

Do you guys have any ideas why it happened?

Thanks,

Comment: They released an update to some Nexus devices recently fixing some bugs.